# Question about Analytic function for series solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello all I am having a bit of confusion in regard to the following;

I understand that when we are working with ODE of the form

$$p_o(x)y''(x)+p_1(x)y'(x)+p_2(x)y(x)=0$$ and we are considering some singular point say $x_o$.

I know then for if all p polynomials, we can use the limit method to determine if it is regular or irregular singular point.

But also I know it must hold in general for all analytic functions and the limit method can only be used with polynomials.

So my question is, how can I know if something is analytic. I know the definition of it, i.e. , if it has a convergent power series at $x_o$, but surely we are not supposed to construct a taylor series for each function we see to do this?

Any advice? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same methods should be usable here for analytic functions (or more generally, meromorphic functions) as for polynomials.  For example, 
the Wikipedia page ["Regular singular point"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point) deals with the coefficients being meromorphic functions.  In your case, you want $p_1(z)/p_0(z)$ to have at most a pole of order $1$ and $p_2(z)/p_0(z)$ at most a pole of order $2$ at $x_0$, which will be true if $(z-x_0) p_1(z)/p_0(z)$ and 
$(z - x_0)^2 p_2(z)/p_0(z)$ are analytic and bounded in a deleted neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $p_{1}(x)/p_{0}(x)$ in the complex $z$ plane. This can then be broken into real and imaginary components $p_{1}(z)/p_{0}(z) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.

Then inside some region where $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &=& \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} &=& - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\end{eqnarray}

$p_{1}(z)/p_{0}(z)$ will be analytic. So if your point of interest $z_0=x_0$ lies inside such region then $p_{1}(x)/p_{0}(x)$ will be analytic at the point $x_0$.